# Maple: simplifying Im(a+I*b) - why it does not work for me?

Tags: maple

So I want to simplify `z:=a+I*b;  Im(z)` where `a`, `b` are real variables So I try:

```
s:= 1+2*I
Im(s) // outputs 2
z:=a+I*b
Im(z) // outputs  Im(a+I*b)
```

So I wonder is it any how possible to simplify `Im(z)` so to get b as output (here we look at general case meaning `z` could be any complex expression from real values (like `a`, `b`, `c` etc and complex `I`))?

Comment: Carefu, do you mean `c*d` when you write `cd` on two occasions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell Maple that a and b were real, so the simplification doesn't work because it doesn't necessarily hold.  One way to get what you want is by using the assume command to let it know:

```
> s:=1+2*I;
                                 s := 1 + 2 I

> Im(s);
                                       2

> z:=a+I*b;
                                 z := a + b I

> Im(z);
                                  Im(a + b I)

> assume(a,real);
> assume(b,real);
> z;
                                   a~ + b~ I

> Im(z);
                                      b~
```

Answer (score 1):

The `evalc` command works by considering unknowns as being real.

```
z:=a+I*b:

Im(z);
                             Im(a + I b)

evalc( Im(z) );
                                  b
```

See its help-page, [?evalc](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=evalc).